# Is there any physical system which has this kind of Hamiltonian?

Tags: classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, action

I am studying Hamiltonian mechanics and much of the examples involve Hamiltonians of the form $H(p,q)=T(p)+V(q)$ where $T$ is the kinetic energy and $V$ is some potential. Of course the theory works beautifully with any other kind of function, but if I have the following function:
\begin{equation}
H(p,q) = p + e^p\cos(q) 
\end{equation}
is there any possible physical system that could have $H$ as its Hamiltonian?

Comment: A canonical transformation can turn that into $H=q + e^q \cos(p)$. The potential energy is then unbounded from below, so I think it's pretty unphysical. Then again, I've seen a real system like that (current biased Josephson junction) so maybe it is possible.

Comment: Excuse me, how do you "see" the potential energy in this example? The only thing I can think of is getting to the Lagrangian via the inverse Legendre transform and try to figure out what it could be in a more familiar setting in configuration space.

Comment: The stuff in $H$ involving $q$ is the potential by definition.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand... you mean that the whole Hamiltonian is the potential? It does not make sense to me.

Comment: I didn't say the whole thing. Just the terms involving $q$.

Comment: @DanielSank I think the canonical transformation you have in mind would map $q\mapsto p$ but $p\mapsto -q$ (well... at least one - sign somewhere so the transformation is symplectic).

Comment: @zerothehero oops, you're right. I think the argument stands though.

Comment: @marcotrevi is there any restriction on the range of $p$ and $q$?

Comment: no, not really...